# How can I capture the audio from a specific program using Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, audio, streaming

Do I have to use CoreAudio for this?

Is there any simple way that anyone knows of? After googling for a couple of hours, I'm more confused than when I started.

Specifically, I am trying to stream the audio from Firefox or chrome over my LAN. Does that make it any easier? (I was trying to find perhaps a built in API supported by either web browser to stream the audio to my obj c program)

Any insights or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to do this for a program you're developing, or do you simply want to stream audio from a web browser?

Comment: For a program that I am developing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public API to capture audio output. You could integrate the open-source [soundflower](http://code.google.com/p/soundflower/) system extension (which creates virtual input and output devices, with the output devices feeding into input devices) into your application. Note that you'll need to capture all system sound, as browsers generally don't have a configurable preference for what output device they use. For comparison, media applications often let you pick what output device they use, so the output of those can be isolated when capturing.

Comment: So I would read from the virtual output device? Do you have a code example of how to do this? I assume I'd read it as soon some of stream. Do you think I could then apply compression and send it over a UDP connection?

Comment: @stormist: you'd read from the input device (output devices are written to, which is what makes them output devices). The system writes to the output device, which then feeds the virtual input device. I don't have any particular code samples, but you'd use Core Audio in the standard way, so any example of reading from specific input devices would work. You could then do whatever you wish with the stream, including compressing the audio and streaming it.

Comment: ...  I've done this with existing applications, running the mic input through audio effects filters in AU Lab, then out through soundflower. Skype then uses the soundflower input device, which (naturally) compresses the audio and transmits over the network. Result: I sound like a Dalek.